# Reading from URL that returns JSON and filling html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This question is very similar to this question ([How to fill form with JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937519/how-to-fill-form-with-json)). The difference is that the JSON comes from a URL, and I don't know how to read the JSON returned from that URL and store in `var`.

URL: `http://MyServer/Results.json`

This call returns this JSON:

```
{ 
  "id" : 12,
  "name": "Jack",
  "description": "Description"
}
```

I only need to fill `<input>` *description* with the field *"description"* from the JSON stream. The example uses a *loop*:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="id"/>
  <input type="text" name="name"/>
  <input type="text" name="description"/>
</form>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12460434

I will just copy the solution for you...

---

You can use jQuery [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function:

```
$.getJSON('http://MyServer/Results.json', function(data) {
    //data is the JSON string
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery you should look at this answer for pure JS solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499647/1361042

---

To fill the input field you can use:

```
 $("#description").val("10");
```

but therefore you have to set `id="description"` to the input.

---

**Working example**

https://jsfiddle.net/f7mpoyvw/3/

In this example I'm calling the randomuser.me api which will return a random user. From the returned user the email address is written into the description field.

In your example you should then try:

```
$.getJSON('http://MyServer/Results.json', function(data) {
    $("#description").val(data['description']);
});
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you include a complete example?